# Byobu automatically open windows on boot

Tags: boot, ssh, byobu

I really enjoy using byobu and the launch at login feature. I'm trying to figure out the best way to have a byobu session automatically launch on system boot, with several windows running different commands, and have it continue to automatically open that session when I SSH into the box.

I've found ways to do each thing individually, I'm just wondering if there's a nice way to get all of these things working together?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I did not. I got sidetracked, and realized this was a bit more complex than I was expecting, especially once adding in things like jump box configurations. Were you looking for an answer as well?

Answer (score 0):

Example from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/526275/start-python-script-in-byobu-session-at-startup

```
byobu list-sessions | grep my-app || byobu new-session -d -s my-app
byobu list-windows -t my-app | grep start-script || byobu new-window -t my-app -n 'start-script'
byobu send-keys -t my-app:start-script "anything needed to start your app"
```